# Is there a size limit when using BeautifulSoup to parse out data from XML and write to a CSV?

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a python script to take the data results from an API pull and write it to a csv file.

The script works perfectly up until it reaches a certain size due to including a higher level of detail for the data I am pulling. I have confirmed that I get the full data set prior to using BeautifulSoup, but once it gets to BeautifulSoup script it drops most of the data.

This is the portion of my script that I am having trouble with:

```
xml_data = requests.post('https://api.adaptiveinsights.com/api/v36', data=xml, headers=headers)
xml_data = xml_data.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_data, 'xml')
csv_data = soup.find('output').text.strip()
csv_data = csv_data.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')


reader = csv.reader(io.StringIO(csv_data))
header = next(reader)
rows = [row for row in reader if len(row) == len(header)]

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=header)
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

When I do a print after line 2 I always have the full data set. However, when it reaches a certain size and I do a print after line 6 that is not the case. Any thoughts? Struggling to find any info on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: This seems rather brute force. Without access to (a small sample of) the actual XML data, it's hard to see what exactly is going on here. If loading the entire XML result into memory is the bottleneck, maybe just write it to a disk file and then try to use a streaming XML parser to process it piecemeal.

Comment: Hi  Yeah, like @tripleee said we need some more info around the size of the thing you're working with. If you just save the XML to disk, how big is the file? Also, please include a sample of the XML, with all the depth, but maybe only one or two instances that include the `output` nodes. Thanks!

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to check what you get with `find('output')`. If file has many `output` then you should use `find_all('output')` and use `for`-loop` to process every `output`